# Use same colors in bash tab complete and ls

Tags: bash, colors, autocomplete

Bash is using a different color for tab completion than `ls`. For example, my `ls` command uses a red color for a broken symlinks (I'm using `dircolors` to configure it), but if I use `ls Tab`, the color is blue. I already have the `set colored-stats On` in my `.inputrc`.

I remember an option like `set .... ls ''` which did the trick, but I accidentally didn't save this option.

So, how to make bash tab complete use the same colors as `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

add `set colored-stats on` to either `~/.inputrc` or system-wide `/etc/inputrc`.